# '--disable-dev-shm-usage' does not resolve the Chrome crash issue in Docker

Tags: docker, protractor, puppeteer

Since our e2e test has expanded to over 50+ tests we decided to run tests in parallel to speed it up. Since default gitlab pipeline has limited resources (and `dev-shm-size` trick did not worked) we decided to use our own AWS runner. 
For those who are running Protractor tests in Docker it's known that you have to add this flags to prevent the browser crash issue:

```
chromeOptions: {
                args: [
                    "--no-sandbox",
                    "--headless",
                    "--disable-gpu",
                    "--disable-dev-shm-usage"
                ]
```

At least that's what I managed to found so far on the web.

I'm using multicapabilities and Puppeteer to run my e2e tests in Docker with the Chrome arguments provided above. In default gitlab runner tests starts but most likely will randomly fail with random timeout errors. I was trying to resolve this for almost a week when all of sudden it appeared that this timeout issues occurs due to the know bug and what actually happens is that the browser is crashing in docker.
However now (when switched to our runner) I'm facing the "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" error when using AWS runner.

```
[chrome #01] WebDriverError: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
[chrome #01]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 4.4.0-1052-aws x86_64)
```

When using default free Gitlab runner tests are pretty flaky; slow; and fails randomly (that's why we decided to use our own runner). But when using our runner test does not even start due to the error above. And again this error should not occur since all required flags are present in Protractor config.
How can I resolve the `'DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist'` issue when using custom runner?
Here is a part of Protractor config

```
multiCapabilities: [
        {
            browserName: "chrome",
            specs: ["./src/dashboard-spec.ts"],
            chromeOptions: {
                args: [
                    "--no-sandbox",
                    "--headless",
                    "--disable-gpu",
                    "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                    "--window-size=1920,1040",
                ],
                binary: puppeteer.executablePath(),
            },
        },
        {
            browserName: "chrome",
            specs: ["./src/smoke-test.ts"],
            chromeOptions: {
                args: [
                    "--no-sandbox",
                    "--headless",
                    "--disable-gpu",
                    "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                    "--window-size=1920,1040",
                ],
                binary: puppeteer.executablePath(),
            },
        },
    ],
```

**UPDATE**
I'm using

```
webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --versions.chrome 2.44
```

I know you may suggest to update the webdriver but this version is the only one which I managed to get work with Puppeteer

**UPDATE 2**
Docker file:

```
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable xvfb gtk2-engines-pixbuf xfonts-cyrillic xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base xfonts-scalable imagemagick x11-apps default-jre \
      --no-install-recommends \
      ruby && \
      gem install s3_website \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN \
  npm install npm@latest -g &&\
  npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Everything is working fine (except slowness, flakiness, random timeouts etc.etc.) both locally and on free gitlab runner. But not when we are attempting to use our own runner

Comment: Q - why are you using Protractor with Puppeteer?

Comment: Also are you running your Chrome as `root` user? If so, you try changing that.

Comment: @demouser123 I don't know so it probably means 'no'. Is this something that I need to add to CI script?

Comment: (I talking about 'root' user)

Comment: I've had the same issue for a long while... from my understanding you are running tests in Docker, right? If so, please attach your dockerfile

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov please find the updated question

Comment: I see you're installing xvfb, do you use it when you start protractor?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I guess xvfb is not needed when I use protractor since I'm running in headless mode using Puppeteer. That's the same dockerfile I used for local docker and gitlab. I guess it's an unnecessary dependency which we can ignore for now...

Comment: Here is the thing... My project was working fine, until at one moment I started getting your error. I also spent a week dealing with it and the only solution that worked for me was to start protractor with xvfb. Looks like some dependency introduced a bug after an update which doesn't let you start chrome instance. Let me know if you'll find a better solution, or if you need an example how I've done it, ping me

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov Ok I'll try it. Not that easy to find appropriate example since nobody is using xvfb with headless browsers since it does not make sense, but I'll try to combine this two approaches. I will be grateful for any useful links

Comment: Hi Guys, 
Any update regarding the solution of this? we are also facing similar kind of issue

Comment: @YuriyGerasimovich any luck solving this? I'm getting this too. I was able to solve this by starting docker with `--shm-size=128m` flag. But tests are running 3,5 hours instead of 35 mins

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I'm no longer working on this project. The solution was exact the same (increase ram) but the result was still not satisfying. We ended up with structuring tests in the test suits to reduce time needed for run.

Answer (score 12):

Old question but a similar issue nearly drove me to insanity so sharing my solution:

When I updated my Docker image Chrome installation from an old version to Chrome 86, I got this error. My setup was not identical but we were instantiating Chrome through a selenium webdriver.

The solution was to pass the options as `goog:chromeOptions` hash instead of `chromeOptions` hash. I truly don't know if this was a Selenium, Chrome, Chromedriver, or some other update, but maybe some poor soul will find solace in this answer in the future.

Comment: It appears to be a Chromedriver change.....
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

Comment: this also fixes codeception!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem in my case

if I run `df -h` I would get among others this

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       16G   15G  547M  97% /
```

The problem started happening a little earlier, when probably the space was not critical, lets say `80%` and this is why I missed it

I turns out that my `/var/jenkins/workspace` was like 10Gb because I was archiving reports for a year without knowing this, because of my jenkins HTML publisher setting

## The solution for me was

1. to remove old reports from the directory
2. to set `keep-all` flag to `false`, to prevent overfilling in future since I was archiving reports anyway

```
publishHTML([
    allowMissing: true,
    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
    includes: '**/*',
    keepAll: true, <--------------- this guy
    reportDir: 'reports/',
    reportFiles: reports,
    reportName: 'HTML Report',
    reportTitles: tabs
])
```

3. and to add extra 4 Gb to the `/dev/xvda1`

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Good point on looking at the space usage